# Disabling Textbox when Checkbox is true is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a script I followed on disabling textbox whenever the checkbox is uncheck in the gridview:

```js
$(function () {
    //Enable Disable all TextBoxes when Header Row CheckBox is checked.
    $("[id*=chkHeader]").bind("click", function () {
        var chkHeader = $(this);

        //Find and reference the GridView.
        var grid = $(this).closest("table");

        //Loop through the CheckBoxes in each Row.
        $("td", grid).find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {

            //If Header CheckBox is checked.
            //Then check all CheckBoxes and enable the TextBoxes.
            if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
                $("input[type=text]", td).removeAttr("disabled");
            } 
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
                $("input[type=text]", td).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("input[type=text]", td).val = ""
            }
        });
    });

    //Enable Disable TextBoxes in a Row when the Row CheckBox is checked.
    $("[id*=chkResult]").bind("click", function () {

        //Find and reference the GridView.
        var grid = $(this).closest("table");

        //Find and reference the Header CheckBox.
        var chkHeader = $("[id*=chkHeader]", grid);

        //If the CheckBox is Checked then enable the TextBoxes in thr Row.
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
            $("input[type=text]", td).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("input[type=text]", td).val = ""
        } 
        else {
            var td = $("td", $(this).closest("tr"));
            $("input[type=text]", td).removeAttr("disabled");
        }

        //Enable Header Row CheckBox if all the Row CheckBoxes are checked and vice versa.
        if ($("[id*=chkResult]", grid).length == $("[id*=chkResult]:checked", grid).length) {
            chkHeader.attr("checked", "checked");
        } 
        else {
            chkHeader.removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

The ASP code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlItems" runat="server" Height="100%">
           <td colspan="3" class="PrimaryLabelTop" style="height: auto" >
                <asp:Label ID="lbItems" runat="server" CssClass="PrimaryLabel" meta:resourcekey="lblNecropsyFoundResource1" >
                    Necropsy: Itemized Information
                </asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No data available." Width="100%" DataSourceID="dsItems" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueID" HeaderText="ValueID" SortExpression="NecropsyValueID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupE" HeaderText="Group Description" SortExpression="GroupE" ReadOnly="true"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemE" HeaderText="Item Description" SortExpression="ItemE" ReadOnly="true"/>   
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server"/>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkResult" runat="server" Checked='<%# IIf(Eval("Result").ToString() = "Selected", True, False) %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Commment">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" Visible='<%# Bind("AllowMemo")%>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueID" HeaderText="ValueID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ValueID" Visible="false"/>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsItems" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetItemValues" TypeName="HealthWeb.HealthWS.Health">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="SampleID" QueryStringField="QS_LABSAMPLE" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
            </td>
        </asp:Panel>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="PrimaryLabelTop" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" meta:resourcekey="btnSaveResource1" height="26px" style="text-align: center" width="60px" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" meta:resourcekey="btnCloseResource1" height="26px" style="text-align: center" width="60px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Problem 1:
The [chkHeader] is working fine. But when I individually trying to check one [chkResult], it clears the [txtComment] but then enable all the txtComment instead of the particular row I just check.

Problem 2:
From binding the gridview, how do I disable textboxes when checkbox is uncheck?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the connection to vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

You have autopostback=true so it will postback and there is where your value is lost. Handle the controls on the onRowDataBound method, there you can set each rows controls and their properties.

Comment: Should I remove autopostback=true?